Search API Module with Solr: File schema_extra_types.xml could not be fetched from Solr server for validation
I have configured the Search API Drupal module with the Apache Solr search server. Locally I am using DDEV, with the DDEV extension and there everything does work.
I do have a VServer for testing purpose, where I do use a Docker compose setup. There is Solr configured. However, I can index my search index, but I do get this error on my Search API server configuration page:
File schema_extra_types.xml could not be fetched from Solr server for validation: Solr endpoint http://solr:8983/ internal Solr server error (code: 500, body: { "responseHeader":{ "status":500, "QTime":0}, "error":{ "msg":"Cannot invoke \"java.net.URL.toURI()\" because the return value of \"java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)\" is null", "trace":"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"java.net.URL.toURI()\" because the return value of \"java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)\" is null\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.ShowFileRequestHandler.getAdminFileFromFileSystem(ShowFileRequestHandler.java:365)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.ShowFileRequestHandler.showFromFileSystem(ShowFileRequestHandler.java:199)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.ShowFileRequestHandler.handleRequestBody(ShowFileRequestHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:226)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2886)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.executeCoreRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:910)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:596)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.dispatch(SolrDispatchFilter.java:262)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(SolrDispatchFilter.java:219)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.traceHttpRequestExecution2(ServletUtils.java:249)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.rateLimitRequest(ServletUtils.java:215)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:213)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:210)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:598)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1580)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1384)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1553)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1306)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:149)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:228)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:301)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:822)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1598)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:753)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:501)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:287)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:421)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:390)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:277)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.run(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:199)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\n", "code":500}} , message: Solr HTTP error: OK (500) { "responseHeader":{ "status":500, "QTime":0}, "error":{ "msg":"Cannot invoke \"java.net.URL.toURI()\" because the return value of \"java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)\" is null", "trace":"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"java.net.URL.toURI()\" because the return value of \"java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)\" is null\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.ShowFileRequestHandler.getAdminFileFromFileSystem(ShowFileRequestHandler.java:365)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.ShowFileRequestHandler.showFromFileSystem(ShowFileRequestHandler.java:199)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.ShowFileRequestHandler.handleRequestBody(ShowFileRequestHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:226)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2886)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.executeCoreRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:910)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:596)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.dispatch(SolrDispatchFilter.java:262)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(SolrDispatchFilter.java:219)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.traceHttpRequestExecution2(ServletUtils.java:249)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.rateLimitRequest(ServletUtils.java:215)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:213)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:210)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:598)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1580)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1384)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1553)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1306)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:149)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:228)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:301)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:822)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1598)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:753)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:501)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:287)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:421)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:390)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:277)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.run(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:199)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\n", "code":500}} ).


This is my Docker compose setup:
services:

  drupal:
    image: jepster/drupal-java:10.2.10
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"
    container_name: ddd-drupal
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/opt/drupal
      - ../web:/var/www/html
      - ./settings.local.php:/opt/drupal/web/sites/default/settings.local.php
      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - solr
    environment:
      - DRUPAL_DB_HOST=mariadb
      - DRUPAL_DB_NAME=drupal
      - DRUPAL_DB_USERNAME=root
      - DRUPAL_DB_PASSWORD=drupal

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.11
    container_name: ddd-mariadb
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: drupal
      MARIADB_DATABASE: drupal
      DB_HOST: localhost
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ../setup/db-dump-dev.sql.gz:/opt/db-dump-dev.sql.gz
      - ./import-dump.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/import-dump.sh

  solr:
    image: solr:9.6
    container_name: ddd-solr
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./solr-conf:/ddd-core-config
    command:
      - solr-precreate
      - drupal
      - /ddd-core-config

volumes:
  mariadb_data:
  solr_data:


My Solr server config looks like this:

Instead of solr as Solr host I also tried localhost. But then I am not able to index the search index. If I specify solr, then I am able to run the indexing process:

I guess that my docker-compose.yml file is wrong. Do you have any idea? Is there any recommended docker-compose.yml file for testing servers (not DDEV)?

Did you use the the "Upload Configset" button, excute search-api-solr:upload-configset, or place the Drupal-specific configset manually into the Solr container via one of those volume mounts or scripts? You have to do one of those probably.

Thanks for your reply. I did this already via the volume mount in my docker-compose.yml file:
'''
volumes:
- ./solr-conf:/ddd-core-config
command:
- solr-precreate
- drupal
- /ddd-core-config
'''
Do you have any other ideas?

You must show the contents of the volume and the code in the scripts. Otherwise we would have to just guess at answers. The overwhelming likelihood is that a schema file is missing.

If I check whats mounted in the Solr Docker container, then the exptected file is definitely there:
solr@eb27f04a2193:/ddd-core-config$ ls
accents_de.txt   elevate.xml   protwords_de.txt   schema_extra_fields.xml  schema.xml            solrconfig_index.xml  solrconfig_requestdispatcher.xml  solrcore.properties  stopwords_und.txt  synonyms_und.txt
accents_und.txt  nouns_de.txt  protwords_und.txt  schema_extra_types.xml   solrconfig_extra.xml  solrconfig_query.xml  solrconfig.xml                    stopwords_de.txt     synonyms_de.txt
solr@eb27f04a2193:/ddd-core-config$

I ended up at defining a network for my Docker services, so the services can communicate with each other. I still get the error on my search api admin page (File schema_extra_types.xml could not be fetched from Solr server), after cache flush. But the search functionality works as expected. So the current config is OK for my purpose.
See my final config with the networks definition below:
services:

  drupal:
    image: jepster/drupal-java:10.2.10
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"
    container_name: ddd-drupal
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/opt/drupal
      - ../web:/var/www/html
      - ./settings.local.php:/opt/drupal/web/sites/default/settings.local.php
      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - solr
    environment:
      - DRUPAL_DB_HOST=mariadb
      - DRUPAL_DB_NAME=drupal
      - DRUPAL_DB_USERNAME=root
      - DRUPAL_DB_PASSWORD=drupal
      - SOLR_HOST=ddd-solr
      - SOLR_PORT=8983
      - SOLR_USERNAME=solr
      - SOLR_PASSWORD=SolrRocks
    networks:
      application:
        aliases:
          - ddd.local

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.11
    container_name: ddd-mariadb
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: drupal
      MARIADB_DATABASE: drupal
      DB_HOST: ddd.local
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ../setup/db-dump-dev.sql.gz:/opt/db-dump-dev.sql.gz
      - ./import-dump.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/import-dump.sh
    networks:
      - application

  solr:
    image: solr:9.6
    container_name: ddd-solr
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./solr-conf:/ddd-core-config
    command:
      - solr-precreate
      - drupal
      - /ddd-core-config
    networks:
      - application

volumes:
  mariadb_data:
  solr_data:

networks:
  application:
    driver: bridge


